# Approximate solutions to nonlinear differential equations using an integral sequence

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, fixed-point-theorems, integral-equations

Let $f:R\times R^n \rightarrow R^n$ be a vector field such that the equation

$$
\dot{x} = f(t,x), \ \ x(t_0) = x_0,
$$

has a unique solution $x(t)$ on the interval $[t_0,t_1]$. Note that we can rewrite the solution as the Volterra integral

$$
x(t) = x_0 + \int_{t_0}^tf(s,x(s))\ ds,
$$

and can (sometimes) seek a solution by studying the limit of the sequence
$$
x^{(n+1)}(t) = x_0 + \int_0^tf(s,x^n(s))\ ds, \ \ x^0(t) = x_0.
$$
Now suppose we define an operator $P$ on $C[t_0,t_1]$ by $P(\cdot) = x_0 + \int_0^tf(s,\cdot)\ ds$. The sequence above can then be considered to be a dynamical system on $C[t_0,t_1]$. The fixed points of this system correspond to solutions of the original nonlinear differential equation and in some cases, such as when $P$ turns out to be a contraction, we can show that the sequence above converges to the fixed point.

To what extent has this sort of approach been investigated in the literature?

Comment: I have tried this approach before, the integrals usually get too complicated too fast. I saw a reference to this method in Elsgolts "Differential Equations and the Calculus of Variations", but it was just mentioned as one of the methods, no discussion was provided. Here's a link in case you would like to search for yourself (I only remember it was somewhere in the beginning) https://archive.org/details/ElsgoltsDifferentialEquationsAndTheCalculusOfVariations